# Where is Gtk+ default theme saved

Tags: linux, gnome, themes, gtk

I've created several customized Gtk+ themes, more or less following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/47699). They are all created under `~/.themes/` folder, and they are all working fine.

However, my question is, how come the system know which one of the themes under `~/.themes/` is the current one that I'm using? I want to backup that file to save my configuration. I know it is not `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. So what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current theme is not stored in a configuration file *per se*. It is a setting managed with dconf, which you can learn more about at [GNOME's documentation page on the subject](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/dconf).

The exact setting is `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-theme` for GNOME and Unity and `/org/mate/desktop/interface/gtk-theme` for MATE. You can use dconf-editor to look at settings like these. It will show you the current value and the system default value.

You can also use the dconf command-line tool. `dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-theme` will show you the current value.

System themes are stored in `/usr/share/themes/`. This is the system-wide equivalent of your `~/.themes/` directory. The directory matching the name of the value of your dconf setting is your current gtk theme.

Comment: Thanks! Please add that for mate, the choice is stored in `mate/desktop/interface`

Comment: Also check out the dconf GUI editor available as a flatpak, it will easily show the default values and your personalized ones... but hey as a person who always liked to explore settings and customize them, please take this advice from a version of me few years later down the road.... when it feels tempting to customize something you don't absolutely need to change, then DON'T ! Or, months later you WILL end up fighting against yourself for a solution to something you've broken in a way no one ever did before... Not a funny experience, trust me, been there enough times...