# How is my selected theme communicated to gtk?

Tags: themes, gtk, mate

Related to [Where is Gtk+ default theme saved](https://superuser.com/questions/1222414/where-is-gtk-default-theme-saved)

I'm using Mate desktop. I see that my Appearance settings are saved in gsettings:

```
$ gsettings get org.mate.interface gtk-theme
'TraditionalOk'
$ gsettings get org.mate.interface font-name
'Ubuntu 11'
$ gsettings get org.mate.font-rendering dpi 
173.0
```

If I write a simple gtk hello-world program and I link it with just libgtk, with no mate or gnome or desktop libraries, it works. It displays the selected appearance. I'm pretty sure that "org.mate.interface" is not hardcoded into libgtk. And I'd assume that "gsettings" is not hardcoded into libgtk. So how does it get my configuration? Environment variable, dotfile, X server property, what?

Answer (score 2):

> And I'd assume that "gsettings" is not hardcoded into libgtk.

That's a bad assumption, since GSettings *is* the primary configuration storage for most GNOME programs and indeed used for retrieving the theme name in GTK 3 under Wayland. Specifically, gdkdisplay-wayland uses `gtk-theme` in the `org.gnome.desktop.interface` schema.

On X11, however, GTK uses the [XSETTINGS protocol](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/xsettings-spec/), where a separate DE-specific daemon gets various settings from wherever it wants, and republishes them in a standard format using X11's selections mechanism.

> On startup, each client that should identify the settings window by calling XGetSelectionOwner() for the _XSETTINGS_S[N] selection and select for notification on the settings window by calling XSelectInput() with a mask of StructureNotifyMask|PropertyChangeMask.
>
> […] The client can then proceed to read contents of the _XSETTINGS_SETTINGS property from the settings window and interpret according to the information in the "_XSETTINGS_SETTINGS Format" section of this document

Since you're using MATE, `mate-settings-daemon` is the XSETTINGS provider. It reads `org.mate.interface` from GSettings and re-publishes the value as `Net/ThemeName` via XSETTINGS, where GTK can finally retrieve it.

Usage of the XSETTINGS protocol makes the backend irrelevant – e.g. older GNOME and MATE versions used GConf, while Xfce uses XfConf, and there is a standalone *xsettingsd* which uses a text file. (On the other hand, as you can see the protocol is very specific to X11 and cannot be used within Wayland.)

The *xsettingsd* package also comes with a `dump_xsettings` tool which dumps data from whatever provider is currently running.

Note that not all desktop environments run an XSETTINGS provider. For example, using LXDE's `lxappearance` simply edits the configuration files: `~/.gtkrc-2.0` for GTK 2, and `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` for GTK 3. These are *always* read, but used at the lowest priority – the GSettings or XSETTINGS specified parameters always win.

Summary:

- GTK 3 supports $GTK_THEME to *temporarily* override the theme.
- In Wayland, GTK 3 reads theme name from GSettings, with configuration file as fallback.
- In X11, GTK 2/3 retrieve theme name from an XSETTINGS daemon, with configuration file as fallback.
- GTK 1 does not support anything except file-based configuration (gtkrc).